# Jenkins job setup automation with SVN credentials

Tags: shell, svn, curl, jenkins, credentials

I created a deploy script for a virtual machine (Ubuntu). This script installs SVN, Jenkins, etc, created a job in Jenkins using a curl POST request and an uploaded config.xml (this file contains the job details). 
But then I couldn't set up the SVN credentials with this script.
I only succeeded using the web interface, manually.
Could you tell me how could I do it? I have a url, username and password for the SVN server.

Comment: maybe you could post the script itself?

Comment: curl -X POST "<url>/createItem?name=<Job name>" --data-binary "@<path to config.xml>" -H "Content-Type: text/xml"

This creates the job. The congix.xml uploaded to the machine previously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On an existing Jenkins server, create some credentials for your SVN server:

[image]

These credentials are stored in the $JENKINS_HOME/credentials.xml file.

You can copy this file on your VM with your script.

Regarding your job, you just have to use the relevant credentials in the SVN section:

[image]